# Enable checkboxlist not working in IE, asp.net, jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkboxlist

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkList" runat="server" Enabled="false" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>

<asp:Button ID="btnFoo" runat="server" Text="Test" />

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<% = btnFoo.ClientID %>').click(function () {
            //var targetValue = 2;
            var items = $('#<% = chkList.ClientID %> input:checkbox');
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                //alert(i);
                //if (items[i].value == targetValue) {
                    items[i].checked = true;
                    // break;
                //}
            }

            $('#<%= chkList.ClientID%>input:checkbox').removeAttr('disabled');                                                    return false;
        })
    });
</script>
```

Note: it works in Chrome, FF not in IE

Its not wroking in IE8, here is the below code.
Its checking all checkboxes, but keeps them Disabled, any solution please?

Comment: Whats the source of the rendered page look like? Specifically, the list of the checkboxes?

Comment: <table id="ctl00_cphMain_chkList" disabled="disabled" border="0">
  <tr>
     <td>
        <span disabled="disabled">
           <input id="ctl00_cphMain_chkList_0" type="checkbox"        name="ctl00$cphMain$chkList$0" disabled="disabled" />
           <label for="ctl00_cphMain_chkList_0">1</label>
        </span>
</td>
  </tr><tr>
   <td><span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_cphMain_chkList_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$cphMain$chkList$1" disabled="disabled" /><label for="ctl00_cphMain_chkList_1">2</label></span></td>
  </tr>
 </table>

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `prop` property instead of `.checked`:

```
$("#btn").on("click",function(){
    $('input:checkbox').each(function(){
     $(this).prop("checked", "true");
    });
});
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/hxS7M/1/

**Edit**: This will also make them enabled.

```
$("#btn").on("click",function(){
    $('input:checkbox').each(function(){
     $(this).prop("checked", "true").prop("disabled",false);
    });
});
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/hxS7M/4/

Comment: Sorry, please see my question again:
Its checking all checkboxes, but keeps them Disabled, any solution please?

Answer (score 1):

Everybody's script is working for normal HTML page. However, you are using **button control** and it **posts back to server** unless you explicitly cancel the event.

`checkAll` returns false to onclick event, so that it won't post back to server.

[image]

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeBehind="WebForm7.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2010.WebForm7" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkList" runat="server" Enabled="False">
            <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
        <asp:Button ID="btnFoo" runat="server" Text="Test" 
            OnClientClick="return checkAll();" />
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function checkAll() {
                $('#<% = chkList.ClientID %> :checkbox').each(function () {
                    $(this).prop("checked", "true").prop("disabled",false);
                });
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

***Credit to @Hanlet Escaño.***

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#btnFoo').click(function () {
     $('#chkList input:checkbox').each(function(i,e) {
        $(e).attr("checked", true);                       
     })
   });
})
```

Comment: Should change `attr()` to `prop()`

Comment: please check my question:
Its checking all checkboxes, but keeps them Disabled, any solution please?

Answer (score 0):

To enable them, do this

```
$('#<%= chkList.ClientID%>input:checkbox').prop('disabled', false);
```